# ¿Cómo adaptar un expand/accordion y añadir nuevos efectos - jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo el listado de los enlaces, de los indice de vídeos 100% responsive adaptados a la ayuda de [Risa__B](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91103/c%C3%B3mo-solucionar-errores-en-los-enlaces).

> En mi anterior pregunta fue un gran problema adaptarlo, a pesar de haber sido solo unos pequeños cambios en los estilos `css`

No quiero que la adaptación responsive se vaya a perder y volver al mismo problema anterior, pero ese no es el problema en este fin.

Al listado de vídeos deseo poder añadirle un **Expand** para mostrar y ocultar los contenidos tal como se puede observar en la imagen en la **- Section 1** y añadirle el mismo efecto se podría decir, al añadirle una descripción a cada uno de los vídeos, que se active una flechita cuando un vídeo contenga una descripción y si no existe una descripción que no se muestre la flechita.

**Ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Cómo podría añadir la misma funcionalidad del ejemplo de la imagen, a mi listado de vídeos?

```css
.chapters {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.view li {
  padding: .5% 1%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view li:hover{
  background:#f9f9f9;
}

.rows {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.play { 
  padding-right: 10px;
  /*align-self:center;*/
}

.video-title {
  width:60%;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.view-preview,.length {
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
}

.view-preview{
  width:23%;
}

.length {
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chapters">
  <ul class="view">
   <li>
   <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
   <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
   <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
   <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
   <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
   <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
   <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
   <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
   <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
   </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes emular tu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo hubiese sido mas facil si hubieses compartido ese link antes.

Creo que no ocupa explicaciones porque estan arriba, solo hubieron unos cambios en el Css y cuando damos click para mostrar mas detalles.

Disfrutalo, saludos desde Honduras.

```js
$('.accordion').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
    $this.removeClass("active");
    $this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
    $this.addClass("active");

    $this.parent().parent().find('.panel').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('.panel').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
});


$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
    $this.removeClass("active");

    $this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
    $this.addClass("active");

    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}

ul li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}

ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.toggle:after {
  content: '\002B';
}

.toggle.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.label:empty {
  display: none;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chapters {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.view li {
  padding: .5% 1%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view li:hover {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.rows {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.play {
  padding-right: 10px;
  /*align-self:center;*/
}

.video-title {
  width: 60%;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.view-preview,
.length {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.view-preview {
  width: 23%;
}

.length {
  width: 10%;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display: none;
}

.toogle {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Me acabo de tomar Dos Cervezas haciendo esto</h2>
<h2>Me debes dos cervezas y los puntos de recompensa</h2>

<button class="accordion">Cervezas</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chapters">
    <ul class="view">
      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video<span class="toggle"> </span>
            <ul class="inner">
              <li>Detalles del video</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Ahora Vodka</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chapters">
    <ul class="view">
      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video<span class="toggle"> </span>
            <ul class="inner">
              <li>Detalles del video</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Para terminar Ron Zacapa</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chapters">
    <ul class="view">
      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video<span class="toggle"> </span>
            <ul class="inner">
              <li>Detalles del video</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @LuisFernando  :) disculpa por todo el inconveniente, sobre las cervezas te le seguiré debiendo una dos semanas más ya te enviaré para que te las compré :) sobre los puntos es más que seguro que sí. Amigo faltó el + y el - en los accordiones en las cervezas y un pequeño problema al mostrar el detalle es que la imagen de play se mueve de su hubicacion cuando tengas tiempo me ayudas en dos dos pequeños detalles si. Amigo edita está pregunta no hace falta que vayas a crear otra.

Comment: Hola @J.Mick, se desplaza porque jquey toma que es hijo, creo que eso de puede solventar, es problema es que tu tienes todo el bloque en un <a></a>, por eso se complica un poco. Pero vere como te ayudo a solventar eso. Otra cosa, lo de las cervezas no son acordeones, solo son simples <h1></h1>

Comment: bueno amigo, no ahí problema si se quita la etiqueta `<a`> a todo lo que abarca lo importante es que funcione cómo el ejemplo de la página. Gracias amigo nuevamente.

Comment: ahora ejecutando bien no solo se desplaza el play si no también las letras de vista previa y el tiempo del vídeo

Comment: Vere que solucion podemos brindar, pero a lo mejor es solo CSS

Comment: vale amigo, o si es mejor opción modificar sobre la etiqueta a donde está el contenido del título del vídeo tiempo y play puedes modificarlo lo importante es que no se vaya a perder el responsive que quede igual el responsive si no voy a tener el mismo problema de mi primer pregunta sobre este tema la puedes observar en mi pregunta el enlace está como Risa_B

Comment: Edite una respuesta para que la veas es un ejemplo muy bueno para que estudies el css y ver como se comporta cada elemento @J.Mick

Comment: es genial pero lástima que esté en **bootstrap** pero déjame adivinar copiaste el código del enlace que te envíe. Pero no puedes negar que mi código es un poco más limpio que el de aquella página también estudiaré el css aunque es díficil estudiarlo cuesta mucho pero si lo he hecho pero solo en diseños simples.

Comment: Si, de allí tome el ejemplo, me costó porque tienen el css separado, yo sé que te gusta usar tus propios estilos, pero bootstrap agiliza el proceso de la creación de un sitio, si no quieres usar bootstrap podrías estudiar las funciones de bootstrap para entender cómo es que funciona. Existo y feliz fin de semana. Hasta el Lunes

Answer (score 4):

Bueno, esta vez si espero que sea lo que necesitas, logre conseguir una funcion de Jquey mas facil, disfrutalo:
El jquery lo que verifica si es hijo, de ser asi lo muesta.
y el CSS fue solo estilo.

Saludos.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
    $this.next().slideUp(350);
  } else {
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
  }
});
```

```css
.chapters {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.view li {
  padding: .5% 1%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.view li:hover {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.rows {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

.play {
  padding-right: 10px;
  /*align-self:center;*/
}

.video-title {
  width: 60%;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.view-preview,
.length {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.view-preview {
  width: 23%;
}

.length {
  width: 10%;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}

ul li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}

ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.label:empty {
  display: none;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Clasicas</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <div class="chapters">
        <ul class="view">
          <li>
            <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
              <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
              <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
              <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
              <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a><span class="toggle label label-danger ">+</span>
              <ul class="inner">
                <li>Detalles del video</li>
              </ul>
            </a>
          </li>
          </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
      <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
      <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
      <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
      <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Rancheras</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Banda</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="chapters">
            <ul class="view">
              <li>
                <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
                  <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
                  <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
                  <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
                  <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a><span class="toggle label label-danger ">+</span>
                  <ul class="inner">
                    <li>Detalles del video</li>
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </li>
              </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
  </li>

  <li>Option 3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Romanticas</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Técnicamente cualquier número de elementos anidados</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <div class="chapters">
            <ul class="view">
              <li>
                <a class="rows" href="video.mp4">
                  <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
                  <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
                  <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
                  <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);"></a><span class="toggle label label-danger ">+</span>
                  <ul class="inner">
                    <li>Detalles del video</li>
                  </ul>
                </a>
              </li>
              </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a class="rows" href="video2.mp4">
          <div class="play"><img src="http://www.murata.com/images/icons/moonicons/moonicon-play.png"></div>
          <div class="video-title">audio video audio video audio video</div>
          <div class="view-preview">&nbsp;Vista Previa</div>
          <div class="length">&nbsp;02:34</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Option 2</li>

  <li>Option 3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Genial amigo :) Gracias ahora lo estudio.

Comment: lo he probado pero existen tres pequeños problemas, en el accordion de **clasicas** debe tener el **+** a lado del enlace "clasicas" y al mostrar el contenido el **más (+)** pasar a ser **-** igualmente  al mostrar el detalle el **+** debe ponerse en **-** y al ocultar el **-** debe ponerse en **+** y el `<span></span>` que contiene el más debe estar juntos en el titulo del vídeo, es decir en: "audio video audio video audio video"

Comment: Solo es una ayuda. @J.Mick

Comment: puedes observar  [este enlace](https://www.udemy.com/programacion-de-android-desde-cero/) si te diriges al medio de la página donde se encuentra el detalle o los indices del vídeo del curso en el primer accordion denominado introducción, si das clic en el **+** el **+** se convierte en **-** ahora en el vídeo donde dice **introducción** o en el vídeo **como seguir este curso** a lado se encuentra una flecha hacia abajo si das clic en la flecha muestra el detalle pero la flecha se pone ahora hacia arriba.

Comment: Entiendo, yo asi lo habia pero con bootstrap, si tengo tiempo te ayudo. @J.Mick

Answer (score 1):

Es solo un ejemplo de todo el codigo que deberas de escribir. Puedes explorarlo, lleva bootstrap por diseño, y el css esta en links externos

```html
<link href="https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/js/webpack/v5/course-landing-page/desktop/hb.6e1c07383f3a2a838d7c2eb9668cb7f1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/js/webpack/v5/entry-main.314642c6da280521a2420a4b39ddf9fa.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/js/webpack/v5/entry-main.314642c6da280521a2420a4b39ddf9fa.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xxs-8 left-col">
  <div class="clp-component-render">

    <div user-tracker-in-viewport="" data-user-tracker-page="clp" data-user-tracker-schema="clp-activity">
      <div data-user-tracker-object-id="957106" data-user-tracker-action="seen-curriculum">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="curriculum-wrapper" data-purpose="course-curriculum" curriculum-loader="" data-course-id="957106" data-course-preview-path="/957106/preview/" data-num-displayed-items="10" data-has-more-to-load="1">

      <span id="curriculum" class="in-page-offset-anchor" style="top: -88px;"></span>

      <div class="curriculum-header-container">
        <div class="header-left">
          <div class="curriculum-header-title">

            Programa de este curso

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-right">
          <span class="js-toggle-all">
                        
                            <div class="collapsed-text">
                                <a class="sections-toggle" user-tracker-click="" data-user-tracker-schema="action-logs" data-user-tracker-object-id="957106" data-user-tracker-action="full-curriculum-read" data-user-tracker-user-id="">
                                    Ampliar todo
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="expanded-text">
                                <a class="sections-toggle">
                                    Contraer todo
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="num-lectures">
                                274 clases
                            </div>
                        
                    </span>
          <span class="curriculum-header-length">
                        40:14:12
                    </span>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="section-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".lecture-957106-1">
          <div class="section-header-left">
            <span class="lecture-title">
                            <div class="lecture-title-toggle-wrapper">
                                <span class="lecture-title-toggle js-curriculum-collapse lecture-957106-1 collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                                    <span class="lecture-title-toggle-plus">+</span>
            <span class="lecture-title-toggle-minus">–</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <span class="lecture-title-text">Introducción</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="section-header-right">
          <span class="num-sections js-curriculum-collapse lecture-957106-1 collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                            
                                2 clases
                            
                        </span>
          <span class="section-header-length">
                            05:58
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lectures-container js-curriculum-collapse lecture-957106-1 collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">

        <div class="lecture-container  lecture-container--preview " data-purpose="lecture-item-1-1">
          <div class="left-content">
            <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
            <div class="top">

              <div class="description collapse description-957106-1-1">
                <p>Introducción al curso de Desarrollo de Aplicaciones y Juegos para Android con una visión global del contenido&nbsp;</p>
              </div>

              <div class="title">

                <a open-modal="" href="javascript:void(0)" data-template-url="/957106/preview/?startPreviewId=7072582" data-course-id="957106" data-lecture-id="5722726" course-impression-tracker="" data-additional-class="generic-modal--previews-video" data-tracking-type="lecture-preview">
                                                Introducción
                                            </a>


                <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-1-1" data-purpose="lecture-caret-1-1"></i>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="details">

            <a open-modal="" href="javascript:void(0)" data-template-url="/957106/preview/?startPreviewId=7072582" data-course-id="957106" data-lecture-id="5722726" course-impression-tracker="" data-additional-class="generic-modal--previews-video" data-tracking-type="lecture-preview"
              data-purpose="preview-course">
              <span class="preview-text">Vista previa</span>
            </a>

            <span class="content-summary">
                                    02:20
                                </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-1-2">
          <div class="left-content">
            <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
            <div class="top">

              <div class="description collapse description-957106-1-2">
                <p>Aquí te explicaré como está estructurado el curso, qué temas tratará cada tutor y cómo beneficiarte plenamente de todo el material que se ha preparado para ti</p>
              </div>

              <div class="title">

                Como seguir este curso


                <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-1-2" data-purpose="lecture-caret-1-2"></i>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="details">

            <span class="content-summary">
                                    03:38
                                </span>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="section-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".lecture-957106-2">
        <div class="section-header-left">
          <span class="lecture-title">
                            <div class="lecture-title-toggle-wrapper">
                                <span class="lecture-title-toggle js-curriculum-collapse collapse lecture-957106-2 ">
                                    <span class="lecture-title-toggle-plus">+</span>
          <span class="lecture-title-toggle-minus">–</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <span class="lecture-title-text">Introducción a Java</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="section-header-right">
        <span class="num-sections js-curriculum-collapse collapse lecture-957106-2 ">
                            
                                15 clases
                            
                        </span>
        <span class="section-header-length">
                            02:19:20
                        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lectures-container collapse js-curriculum-collapse lecture-957106-2 ">

      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-1">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-1">
              <p>Aprender java puede ser fácil y divertido. Con este tutorial te introducirás en la programación en Java.</p>
              <p><br></p>
              <p><br></p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              Introducción a Java


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-1" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-1"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    04:24
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-2">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-2">
              <p>Normas de sintaxis que debes cumplir en Java para que tu código pueda ejecutarse</p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              Sintaxis en Java


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-2" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-2"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    06:07
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container  lecture-container--preview " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-3">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-3">En este video veras ejemplos de las variables mas basicas de Java para los tipos de datos más usados</div>

            <div class="title">

              <a open-modal="" href="javascript:void(0)" data-template-url="/957106/preview/?startPreviewId=7066256" data-course-id="957106" data-lecture-id="5944750" course-impression-tracker="" data-additional-class="generic-modal--previews-video" data-tracking-type="lecture-preview">
                                                Variables
                                            </a>


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-3" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-3"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <a open-modal="" href="javascript:void(0)" data-template-url="/957106/preview/?startPreviewId=7066256" data-course-id="957106" data-lecture-id="5944750" course-impression-tracker="" data-additional-class="generic-modal--previews-video" data-tracking-type="lecture-preview"
            data-purpose="preview-course">
            <span class="preview-text">Vista previa</span>
          </a>

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    13:04
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-4">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-4">
              <p>En este video verás como declarar arrays y hacer uso de ellos a través del índice</p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              Arrays


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-4" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-4"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    08:40
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-5">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-5">
              <p>En este video verás como crear una matriz y acceder a cada una de las posiciones de ésta</p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              Matrices


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-5" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-5"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    07:34
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-6">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-6">
              <p>En este video veras como funciona el condicional if - else, ademas de la explicación de operadores de comparación</p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              if y operadores de comparación


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-6" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-6"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    11:57
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-7">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-7">
              <p>En este video veremos operadores de calculo y sus abreviaturas para trabajar con los datos de las variables</p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              Operadores de cálculos


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-7" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-7"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    08:43
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-8">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-8">
              <p>En este video veras&nbsp;operadores booleanos and y or</p>
            </div>

            <div class="title">

              Operadores lógicos


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-8" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-8"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">

          <span class="content-summary">
                                    12:12
                                </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>


      <div class="lecture-container " data-purpose="lecture-item-2-9">
        <div class="left-content">
          <span class="udi udi-play-circle"></span>
          <div class="top">

            <div class="description collapse description-957106-2-9">En este video verás como usar Switch con case, default y break</div>

            <div class="title">

              Switch


              <i class="udi udi-caret-down down-arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".description-957106-2-9" data-purpose="lecture-caret-2-9"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details">
```

Comment: Esta muy bien tu respuesta, pero debes tomar en cuenta las etiquetas de la pregunta y en ella no describe utilizar `bootstrap`

Comment: @LuisFernando Es exactamente lo que quería pero en mi código, una pena que esté con **bootstrap**. He actualizado mi pregunta yo tengo un pequeño script de jQuery ese me gustaría añadirle a mi código adaptar el código jQuery a mi código.

Comment: @LuisFernando no me gusta utilizar **bootstrap** me gusta más crear mi propios diseños, mi propio código más optimizado.

Comment: Pero solo uso bootstrap para los Accordion, tu codigo sigue estando alli, pero si no te gusta la respuesta, ni modo. Solo queria ayudar, lo siento. @J.Mick,

Comment: Tengo una duda, no quieres usar bootstrap pero si quieres hacerlo con Jquery? O quieres usar puro CSS?

Comment: @LuisFernando no quiero usar  **bootstrap** amigo, si ejecutas mi pregunta tengo un código **jQuery** que se podría adaptar a mi código y en el accordio añadir sólo puro css

Comment: @LuisFernando Tengo dos ejecuciones en mi pregunta la puedes ejecutar si es posible adaptar aquel código es mucho más simple y entendible que estudiar tanto código, tener que ver la documentación de **bootstrap** para poder ver funcionamiento etc... es mejor el propio código así es más facil poder entender o al fin uno sabe como funciona.

Comment: Utilizar Jquery tambien incluye Jquery UI? @J.Mick